# rotate object 0 to 90 with speed 1 then wait then 90 to 0 degree with 1 speed unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i want to Rotate my object 0 to 90 degree with 1 speed --> then wait for 3 Sec ---> Then Rotate again 90 to 0 degree with 1 speed --> Then wait for 3 sec

i need above process in loop

i m success with it but it working only 1 time in Start Function

In update function its not working

below my Start Function code

```
IEnumerator Start()
{
    StartCoroutine( RotateMe1(Vector3.forward * 90f, 1f));
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
    StartCoroutine(RotateMe2(Vector3.forward * 0f, 1f));
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
}

IEnumerator RotateMe1(Vector3 byAngles1, float inTime1)
{
    var fromAngle1 = transform.rotation;
    var toAngle1 = Quaternion.Euler(transform.eulerAngles + byAngles1);
    for (var t = 0f; t < 1; t += Time.deltaTime / inTime1)
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(fromAngle1, toAngle1, t);
        yield return null;
    }
}

IEnumerator RotateMe2(Vector3 byAngles2, float inTime2)
{
    var fromAngle2 = transform.rotation;
    var toAngle2 = Quaternion.Euler(transform.eulerAngles + byAngles2);
    for (var t = 0f; t < 1; t += Time.deltaTime / inTime2)
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(fromAngle2, toAngle2, t);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Below my Update Function code

```
void Update()
{
    StartCoroutine(RotateMe1(Vector3.forward * 90f, 1f));
    StartCoroutine(Wait());
    StartCoroutine(RotateMe2(Vector3.forward * 0f, 1f));
    StartCoroutine(Wait());
}

IEnumerator RotateMe1(Vector3 byAngles1, float inTime1)
{
    var fromAngle1 = transform.rotation;
    var toAngle1 = Quaternion.Euler(transform.eulerAngles + byAngles1);
    for (var t = 0f; t < 1; t += Time.deltaTime / inTime1)
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(fromAngle1, toAngle1, t);
        yield return null;
    }
}

IEnumerator RotateMe2(Vector3 byAngles2, float inTime2)
{
    var fromAngle2 = transform.rotation;
    var toAngle2 = Quaternion.Euler(transform.eulerAngles + byAngles2);
    for (var t = 0f; t < 1; t += Time.deltaTime / inTime2)
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(fromAngle2, toAngle2, t);
        yield return null;
    }
}

IEnumerator Wait()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
}
```

[Here i recorded Video for issue of Update Function](https://youtu.be/nxnFzf6Ethk)

i attached above script on AXE in attached above Video

PLease help me

Comment: *"In update function its not working"* Ok so why not also post the version of the update function that that is not working? While at it please explain "not working".

Comment: its work but not same as Start Function. i uploaded video of that issue check it.

Comment: That's not good at-all. You want it to repeat again after waiting for the last 3 seconds? Repeat forever?

Comment: ya i need to repeat forever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening is that you are starting cooruines every frame without waiting for the one to finish. This results to hundreds or even thousands of coroutines trying to modify an Object rotation at the-same time. Sorry, you can't wait in the Update function. You can try with a `boolean` variable but coroutines are used to accomplish this kind of stuff.

If you want it to rotate forever, put it in a while loop.

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(rotateForever());
}

IEnumerator rotateForever()
{
    while (true)
    {
        StartCoroutine(RotateMe1(Vector3.forward * 90f, 1f));
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
        StartCoroutine(RotateMe2(Vector3.forward * 0f, 1f));
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
    }
}
```

You can optimize the rotateForever function:

```
IEnumerator rotateForever()
{
    WaitForSeconds waitTime = new WaitForSeconds(3);
    while (true)
    {
        StartCoroutine(RotateMe1(Vector3.forward * 90f, 1f));
        yield return waitTime;
        StartCoroutine(RotateMe2(Vector3.forward * 0f, 1f));
        yield return waitTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: i got 1 more issue When i m Changing (Vector3.forward * 90f, 1f)) to (Vector3.forward * 90f, 2f)). its rotating around 80 dregre then come back. its not rotate complete 90 degree

Comment: If you want to make sure that all rotation finish before waiting, the change all the `StartCoroutine...`  to `yield return StartCoroutine...`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a single coroutine to do the job, use it instead.
Basically, this.

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(RotateMe(Vector3.forward * 90f, 1f));
}

IEnumerator RotateMe(Vector3 byAngles1, float inTime1)
{
    while (true)
    {
        var fromAngle1 = transform.rotation;
        var toAngle1 = Quaternion.Euler(transform.eulerAngles + byAngles1);
        for (var t = 0f; t < 1; t += Time.deltaTime / inTime1)
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(fromAngle1, toAngle1, t);
            yield return null;
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
        byAngles1 *= -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: The bad side is that OP cannot change the wait time to be different from each 2 rotations if that's needed in the future.

Comment: I liked how you did it in a single coroutine! However I don't like the usage of the implicit type `var`: I think it should only be used when dealing with anonymous types ;)